# SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable withAnimation invalid

Tags: swiftui

I want to implement UIScrollView in UIKit using UIViewRepresentable in SwiftUI.
But I have a problem that UIScrollView implemented via UIViewRepresentable bridge can't perform animation with withAnimation .

To find the cause of the problem, I used a ScrollView in SwftUI as a comparison. By comparison, it is found that SwftUI ScrollView executes withAnimation normally; however, UIScrollView implemented through UIViewRepresentable bridge cannot specify animation.

May I ask if it is because of my incorrect use of UIViewRepresentable updateUIView?

I also found related articles, such as https://github.com/rcarver/swift-matched-animation It seems that the solution is mentioned, but it does not actually solve my problem.

English is not very good, I don't know if I can understand this description

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct FriendView: View {
    
    @State var display = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // UIViewRepresentable + UIKit
            UScrollView {
                VStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .fill(self.display ? .red.opacity(0.3) : .blue.opacity(0.3))
                        .frame(width: 200, height: self.display ? 200 : 100)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.display.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            
            // SwiftUI
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .fill(self.display ? .red.opacity(0.3) : .blue.opacity(0.3))
                        .frame(width: 200, height: self.display ? 200 : 100)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.display.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the specific implementation of UIScrollView in UIKit

```
struct UScrollView<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = UIScrollView
    
    var content: () -> Content
    
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        return view
    }()
    
    var host: UIHostingController<AnyView> = UIHostingController(
        rootView: AnyView(EmptyView())
    )
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        host.rootView = AnyView(self.content())
        host.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(host.view)
        
        scrollView.addConstraints([
            host.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            host.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            host.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            host.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            host.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor)
        ])
        
        return scrollView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        host.rootView = AnyView(self.content())
        host.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        uiView.addSubview(host.view)
        
        uiView.addConstraints([
            host.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.topAnchor),
            host.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.leadingAnchor),
            host.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.trailingAnchor),
            host.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.bottomAnchor),
            host.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.widthAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

Comparing the execution effect, 1 withAnimation is invalid, 2 withAnimation is valid

[image]

Comment: After comparison, what result did you get? I don't understand what you mean by invalid. Also, what's the question??

Comment: @NoeOnJupiter I have added contrast results to the question

Comment: What happens if you don't reset the `host.rootView` in the `updateUIView()` method? Without running the code myself and just looking at it, that would be my first point of inquiry. At the moment, every time a change to the SwiftUI view hierarchy changes, your scroll view's contents are completely reset, which means there's little to no chance of any animation happening.

Comment: State does not work via bridge - use it internally in SwiftUI view injected into representable.